# sub report not getting any value in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a sub report in crystal report ..i am using vb.net
[image]

> delParkingtype.rpt

i created as sub report.then i calling this report to my crystal report viewr like this:

```
        Dim rpt As New DelivaryPerformance
        Dim rpt1 As New DelParkingtype
        Dim locid As Integer = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", CmbLocations.Text)
        Dim cmdstatus As New SqlCommand("IBS_DelivaryStaus", con.connect)
        cmdstatus.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdstatus.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
        da.SelectCommand = cmdstatus
        da.Fill(ds)
        If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then

            rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
            ' CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        End If
        Dim cmdparkingtype As New SqlCommand("IBS_Delivaryparkingtype", con.connect)
        cmdparkingtype.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdparkingtype.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
        da1.SelectCommand = cmdparkingtype
        da1.Fill(ds1)
        If (ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then

            rpt1.SetDataSource(ds1.Tables(0))
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt1
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        End If
```

but

> DelParkingtype not filling any data..what is wrong with my code

Comment: you have to set a datasource to the subreport too

Comment: sir,,i already set dataset to the subreport..that is ds1

Comment: Uhhh sorry I read it wrong! Excuse me!

Comment: it s ok sir..how i can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this, you have to add the datasource to the subreport of your main report. After that you just add the main report to reportSource.

```
rpt.Subreports(0).SetDataSource(ds1.Tables(0))
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
```

You won't need this

```
Dim rpt1 As New DelParkingtype
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: sir..this is ok..but i want to add one more sub report..that value i will take to dataset name ds2..so that time how i will write code

Comment: rpt.Subreports(1).SetDataSource(ds2.Tables(0)) just change the subreport index from 0 to 1